# Whether $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 0 $ when improper integral is convergent?

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove: $f(x)$ continuous function and $\int_a^\infty |f(x)|\;dx \lt \infty$ so $\lim_{ x \to \infty } f(x)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108191/prove-fx-continuous-function-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-infty-so-l)

Assume $f(x)$ **positive** and **continuous**,for improper integrals of the first kind, is there an analog of the $n$-th term divergence test for series ? It would say:
$$
\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)dx\ \hspace{5pt}\mbox{converges}  \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 0.
$$
Give a proof or counterexample.

I think $$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) \neq 0$$ but I can not give a counterexample.