# Fourier Transform of Derivative

Tags: fourier-analysis

Consider a function $f(t)$ with Fourier Transform $F(s)$. So $$F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2 \pi i s t} f(t) \ dt$$

What is the Fourier Transform of $f'(t)$? Call it $G(s)$.So $$G(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2 \pi i s t} f'(t) \ dt$$

Would we consider $\frac{d}{ds} F(s)$ and try and write $G(s)$ in terms of $F(s)$?

Comment: Fourier transform commutes with linear operators. Derivation is a linear operator. Game over.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The Fourier transform of the derivative is (see, for instance, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships))
$$
\mathcal{F}(f')(\xi)=2\pi i\xi\cdot\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi).
$$

Why?

Use integration by parts:
$$
\begin{align*}
u&=e^{-2\pi i\xi t} & dv&=f'(t)\,dt\\
du&=-2\pi i\xi e^{-2\pi i\xi t}\,dt & v&=f(t)
\end{align*}
$$
This yields
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}(f')(\xi)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi i\xi t}f'(t)\,dt\\
&=e^{-2\pi i\xi t}f(t)\bigr\vert_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-2\pi i\xi e^{-2\pi i \xi t}f(t)\,dt\\
&=2\pi i\xi\cdot\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)
\end{align*}
$$
(The first term must vanish, as we assume $f$ is absolutely integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: Thanks integration by parts was the trick.

Comment: Why the first term must vanish? I think we need the additional condition $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=0$ to guarantee this.

Comment: Since $f \in L^1 \cap C^1$ f is continous and integrable, and must tend to zero when t tends to infinity...?

Comment: The limit need not exist, although if it exists it must be zero.  There are smooth, i.e., $C^\infty$, $L^1$ functions that do not tend to zero as $x \to \infty$.  For an example, just make smooth "spikes" of height 1 at each integer $n$, such that the spike at $n$ has width $2^{-n}$.  The limit must be zero, however, if you replace "continuous" with "uniformly continuous."

Comment: Where did we ever assume that $f$ is absolutely integrable, or was that an assumption appended as a bandage?

Comment: It seems that absolute integrability can NOT imply that $f$ vanishes at the infinity. See Did's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108191/prove-that-f-continuous-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-finite-imply-lim-limi

Comment: If $f$ is in the Schwartz space, then it does vanish at infinity, and then your argument works.

Comment: I'm also not 100% following the "first term must be 0" argument. We're not _actually_ evaluating that term _at_ infinity. That doesn't make mathematical sense.

Comment: How does being absolutely integrable imply that the evaluation of a function from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is $0$?

Answer (score 137):

A simpler way, using the [anti-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem):

$$f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) \, e^{i \omega t} d\omega$$

$$f'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\!\left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) \, e^{i \omega t} d\omega \right)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}   i \omega \, F(\omega) \, e^{i \omega t} d\omega$$

Hence the Fourier transform of $f'(t)$ is $ i \omega \, F(\omega)$

Comment: A very good answer indeed. +1

Comment: @leonbloy Why exactly can we move the derivative inside the integral (apply Leibniz rule)?

Comment: @Konstantin why not? As you mentioned, we've used Leibniz rule here as the function inside the integral has a continuous partial derivative w.r.t. the variable t with respect to we're differentiating

Comment: Could you elaborate on how that second inequality tells you that the Fourier transform of $f'(t)$ is $i\omega F(\omega)$?

Comment: @Atsina In general, if you have $g(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  G(\omega) \, e^{i \omega t} d\omega $, then you know that $G(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $g(t)$

Comment: @leonbloy How 'w' came out of the integral as we are integrating with respect to 'dw'? Can anyone elaborate, please?

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but doesn't your answer rely on the fact that the Fourier inversion formula holds for $f$? Which means you are assuming extra conditions on $f$? Like you are saying that $F$ is integrable (which it doesn't have to be in general).

Comment: @UjjawalM. Note that the proof is not $f'(t) =i \omega F(\omega)$ but rather that the Fourier transform of $f'(t)$ is $i \omega F(\omega)$. I got confused too.