# Fourier Transform of a derivative - Integration

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I have been trying to understand the formula for the Fourier Transform of a derivative, but I am getting hung up in the integration. Looking at this [post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430858/fourier-transform-of-derivative)

So far, I understand everything up to the step:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}(f')(\xi)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi i\xi t}f'(t)\,dt\\
&=e^{-2\pi i\xi t}f(t)\bigr\vert_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-2\pi i\xi e^{-2\pi i \xi t}f(t)\,dt\\
&
\end{align*}
$$

I understand also, that since f(t) must vanish, the first term must vanish. It may be that I am missing something easy, but my problem is in understanding how to compute the integral on the right, and why it evaluates to

$$
\begin{align*}
2\pi i\xi\cdot\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: $2\pi i\xi$ is a constant respect to $t$.

Comment: I just realized that I was basically asking how to do a normal Fourier Transform. Thanks for your response