# The Fourier transform of the derivative of a function $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ (That is to say $f$ is absolutely integrable over $\mathbb{R}$) with derivative $f'\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$. The Fourier transform of $f$ is given by: 
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{itx} \text{d}x.
\end{align}
I want to prove that the Fourier transform of $f'$ is given by:
\begin{align}
\widehat{f'}(t) = -it \hat{f}(t).
\end{align}
Here is my own way to give a proof: By definition, we have
\begin{align}
\widehat{f'}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x) e^{itx} \text{ d}x
\end{align}.
By parts, we get 
\begin{align}
\widehat{f'}(t) = \left[f(x)e^{itx}  \right]_{-\infty}^{\infty} - it \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{itx} \text{ d}x.
\end{align}
I wonder why the first term in the preceding equality vanishes? This is my problem. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I believe you need $f'$ to be integrable.

Comment: $f'$ is integrable. I forgot writing this condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We must suppose that $f$ is absolutely continuous for the derivative to really have any meaning.  In that case, the fundamental theorem of calculus gives $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t)\,dt$.  Since $f'$ is in $L^1$, then as $x \to \infty$, dominated convergence implies that $\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt \to \int_0^\infty f'(t)\,dt$; in particular the limit exists.  Thus $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists.  Now if this limit equals anything other than zero, $f$ would not be integrable.  So we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, and a similar argument gives $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) =0$ as well.  Since $e^{itx}$ is bounded, this shows that the term in question does indeed vanish.

Comment: Ok, I actually proved that the limit $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)$ exists by the integrability of $f'$. But how can one use the integrability of $f$ to show that the limit must be zero?. This is not clear for me. 
Anyway, i really appreciate your contribution.

Comment: @HusseinEid: Try drawing a picture of a function with $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = c \ne 0$.  It should be immediately clear that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f| = \infty$, and it should take only a little bit more work to prove it.

Comment: Ok, i will try that.

Answer (score 0):

See:

[Fourier Transform of Derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430858/fourier-transform-of-derivative)