# Fourier transform on Green's function

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, greens-function

I need to do a Fourier transform for the next Green's function:$F[(\frac{\mathrm{d} ^{2}}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}-m^{2})\cdot G(x,x^{'})]$.

My solution is: $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }(\frac{\mathrm{d} ^{2}}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}\cdot G(x,x')\cdot e^{-ikx})dx-m^{2}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }G(x,x')\cdot e^{-ikx}dx=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }(\frac{\mathrm{d} ^{2}}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}\cdot G(x,x')\cdot e^{-ikx})dx-m^{2}\widetilde{G}(k)$

but I don't know how to solve the first integral.

The solution is:$-(k^{2}+m^{2})\cdot \widetilde{G}(k)$

Can someone please explain to me how did they get this expression?

Comment: Looks related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430858/fourier-transform-of-derivative

Comment: Use partial integration twice and then that G(x,x') should vanish for x to $\pm \infty$

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I have completely forgotten about differentiation property of the Fourier transform.