# How to find this limit $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, limits, improper-integrals

let $f(x)\in C^{1}[0,+\infty)$ , and such improper integral
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(|f(x)|+|f'(x)|\right)dx$$ is  convergence

show that
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$$

My try: since
$$(e^xf(x))'=e^x[f(x)+f'(x)]$$
but this problem is 
$$|f(x)|+|f'(x)|$$
so I can't.Thank you

Comment: Is $f$ absolutely continuous?

Comment: Some additional information on the subject (altough not the same) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108191/prove-fx-continuous-function-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-infty-so-l

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\int |f'| < \infty$ and $f(t) = f(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t f'(\tau) d \tau$ we have that $f_\infty = \lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) $ exists. Since $\int|f| < \infty$, we see that we must have $f_\infty =0$.