# Given a continuous function which it's improper integral converges, prove/disprove $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> **Prove/Disprove:**
>
> $(1)$ If $f$ is a continuous function such that $f > 0, \forall x \in [0,\infty)$ and $\int_0^\infty f $ converges, then $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0.$
>
> $(2)$ If $f$ is a continuous and monotonic decreasing function such that $f \geq 0, \forall x \in [0,\infty)$ and $\int_0^\infty f $ converges, then $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0.$

I think $(1)$ is false, but I couldn't find a counter example.

I think $(2)$ is true, tried to prove with Cauchy's criterion for improper integrals and the definition of the limit, but got stuck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (1) give the function a series of humps, of the same height but reducing in width (2) such a function will converge to a limit; what if that limit is nonzero?

Answer (score 2):

Hint for (1): tall thin triangles.

(2) $\int_0^\infty f(x)\; dx \ge x f(x)$.

Comment: I thought about the triangles function, as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108195), and I've used it to prove a previous exercise, where $f$ was non-negative. How can I justify the integral converges, if the triangles' bases are at, say $1/2?$

Comment: The integral doesn't converge if the bases of the triangles are elevated above $y = 0$. However, you can simply take that triangles example with bases at $y = 0$ and add any positive function that's integrable on $[0, \infty)$, such as $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$.

Comment: @MichaelLee So I should take a function which it's the sum of the triangles function and a positive function, such as $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2},$ which gives me a positive function, and since each of the integrals converge, then the sum of them converge?

Comment: That's correct. You can even make the triangle function $f$ such that $g(x) = f(x)+\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ is unbounded as $x\to \infty$ (such as by giving the triangles a height of $2^n$ and a base width of $2^{1-2n}$).

Comment: @MichaelLee Could you please explain Robert's hint for $(2)?$ I understand that it comes from the fact $f$ is decreasing, but I can't see where the $x$ comes from.

Comment: I would tweak it a bit, probably. Consider that a monotonically decreasing function $f$ such that $f > 0$ has a limit $c = \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)\geq 0$. If $c > 0$, then $f\geq c$, so $$\int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\geq \int_0^a c\,\mathrm{d}x = ca$$ for all $a > 0$. This implies that $$\int_0^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\geq \lim_{a\to \infty} ca = \infty$$

Comment: @MichaelLee Ah I see it now, nice! I would also like to understand Robert's approach, any chance you could try to elaborate about it?

Comment: Sure. Consider that $f(x)\geq f(a)$ for all $x\in [0, a]$. Therefore, $$\int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\geq \int_0^a f(a)\,\mathrm{d}x = af(a)$$ Therefore, $$\limsup_{a\to \infty} af(a)\leq \int_0^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ This implies that $\lim_{a\to \infty} f(a) = 0$; otherwise, there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $a$, there is an $x > a$ such that $f(x) > \epsilon$. Therefore, for any $a$, there is an $x > a$ such that $xf(x) > \epsilon x$, which implies that $$\limsup_{a\to \infty} af(a) = \infty$$ This would contradict the fact that $\limsup_{a\to \infty} af(a)$ is finite.

Comment: @MichaelLee Thank you very much :)