# Find a function $f$ with given conditions

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I need a  function   $f(x)$ such that

1. $f(x) $ is non-negative continuous
2. $\int\limits_0^{\infty}f(x)\ dx$ exists
3. $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty }f(x) $ does not  exists

I think such a function doesn't exist because  condition $(2)$ gives that corresponding summation exist  which imply as $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty }f(n)=0 $

Comment: Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108191/prove-that-f-continuous-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-finite-imply-lim-limi)

Comment: @yanko Not necessarily, the limit can also not exist. And $f$ being continuous is also not a necessary requirement, such functions exist even if it is not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about
$$ g_n(x)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}n e^{-n^6(x-n)^2},\qquad f(x) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \sum_{n\geq 1} g_n(x) $$
? $g_n(x)$ is a positive continuous function, concentrated around $x=n$. It is simple to check that $f(x)$ is positive and continuous. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ we have $f(n)\geq g_n(n) = n$, hence $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)$ does not exist. However
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx \leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g_n(x)\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^{5/2}}{6}$$
so $f(x)$ fulfills the wanted constraints.

Comment: May I ask why are you allowed to change the sum and integral signs order? is it because $g_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $R$?

Comment: $\sum_{n\geq 1}g_n(x)$ **does not** converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ (you already know that $f(n)=n$), but the exchange of $\sum$ and $\int$ is allowed by the monotone/dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Build a function that in every interval of type $[n, n+1], n\in N$, the function defines a triangle that becomes smaller and smaller as $n$ grows, and maybe you can write that area of the triangles as $\sum a_n$ with $a_n$ defining the triangle's area in $[n, n+1]$.

Maybe the series is a geometric series?